# create audit table which track each changed columns

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with 10 fields and many users will be changing data on this. I want to report like what a user changed i.e each column information also i need i.e like old and new value. I have to use trigger but how should be the history table look like.?

My idea:
1. Main table
2. History table
3. column table

1. main table is my table on which users act.
2. history table is a auto incremented table with date and user information who made the changes.
3. column table will have a key from history table and column name , old value and new value

Is this the best way of doing?

My another problem is how do i loop through each column in my trigger

Answer (score 0):

Instead create table with column like name and date. and instead storing creating 10 fields create 10 row and created date. whenver a new update is there insert new row with field name and update date.

In this way you can keep  history of it.

```
id   name  value                Date
1    name  suresh           2013-1-1
2    email suresh@gmail.com 2013-1-1
```